# xhtml java Calendar with locales

Tags: java, calendar, locale

i am using calendar icon when i am selecting some date then it is displaying in (just like dd/MM/YYYY) and saving it into db in locale format .

now i am trying to edit that page page so date is populated with locale format not in  dd/MM/YYYY this formate .

So i am saving again then it giving error "invalid time stamp" . which is user define msg if formate does not match respective locale .

So can you please explain how calendar pick respective locale

---

**xhtml page**

```
<ips:calendar id="EditLPNHeaderInbound_ExpirationDate_calendar" showTime="false"  converter="ips.converter.Timestamp"
value="#{lpnBackingBean.IPSDetailData.dataObject.expirationDateString}" size="12"  showfullyear="true">
</ips:calendar>
```

---

### java code

```
public String getExpirationDateString()
{

    if (lpnObject != null && lpnObject.getExpirationDate() != null) {           
        return DTTMFormat.timestampToStringWithShortTZName(lpnObject.getExpirationDate(),
                getLocale(), getContextTimeZone()); 
        String dateStr = 

        DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG, WMMisc.getLocale());
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }      

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        String formatedDate = (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        return formatedDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Don’t save dates as strings, and certainly not as localized strings. The localized format may be changed in the future, so you risk that with the next Java version you won’t be able to read your data. Doesn’t your database have a `date` datatype? Then use it. The localized format belongs in you xHTML page.